# There will be a lot of developers and their `computers` or `computer`, which one is better?

Tags: grammar, expressions

It sounds like the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/_9RGpiWjn_o)

> now that we've explored the relationship between functions and their
>   `gradient`.

[gradient](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/gradient) is a countable noun, So, `gradients` would be better here, right?

similarly, in the following expressions (suppose each developer bring at most 1 computer), one is better than two

expression_1: there will be a lot of developers and their `computers`.

expression_2: there will be a lot of developers and their `computer`.

Is my understanding right?

Comment: You are correct.  It’s not clear to me why, in your example, the speaker says `gradient`.  It may be a mistake or they may want `gradient` to be a mass noun (uncountable noun).

Answer (score 5):

Does each developer have her own computer, i.e. there is more than one computer? Then *computers* is correct. It's possible a *group* of developers are attending, and that they're bringing just a single computer (perhaps a mainframe). Without context, one cannot tell which is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if suppose each developer bring at most 1 computer?

Comment: If it's more than one computer you're talking about, not one per person, then use the plural.